# Virtual Ethernet Adapter / Multiple MAC and IP address for one adapter

Tags: networking, windows-7, virtualization, ethernet

I need to emulate multiple (10+) Ethernet adapters (different MAC and IP, same subnet) through a single Ethernet adapter. I know you can assign multiple IP addresses to a single adapter, but haven't found any solution for multiple MAC address. I am currently doing this by using Linux VMs under VirtualBox with bridged virtual adapters. However, this solution is not optimal for my applications.

I would like to know if it is possible to do the same without a virtual machine setup.

Edit:

Found something for Linux: [Multimac](http://www.primianotucci.com/default.php?view=57), hopefully someone will point me to a Windows based solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by no means tested, but the `tuntap` driver that OpenVPN uses works under Windows.  You can use it to create "virtual" adapters.

Having read through [this article/software page](http://www.klcconsulting.net/Change_MAC_w2k.htm), I don't see why you wouldn't be able to change the MAC of each of these virtual adapters in the registry as described.

Comment: I found out http://colinux.org uses similar technique to create guest adapters, I will dig deep and investigate.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried a similar thing myself and I think the short answer is no.

It is possible to set up multiple vlan interfaces on the same physical interface with different hardware addresses. If you try to do the same thing with subinterfaces in the same vlan however they all just take the last configured mac address.

Answer (score 0):

We have one application which done something similar. We install this thing on windows and we create a virtual adapter to which different mac and different IP is assigned. Both these IP and MAC are provided through configuration file. And this IP is accessible in our network like any other IP. So this is possible.

**WinPcap** is the software used in this set up to create virtual network adapter. This can provide you direction in what you are seek to achieve.